# why doesn't enemy spawn

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a script where i clone enemy from replicated storage and make folder in the workspace a parent of an enemy. But, when i run code, it doesn't show any error and enemy doesn't spawn. I don't what I have to do. HELP

Code:

```
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local anim = rs.EnemiesScripts:FindFirstChild("Animation"):Clone()
local move = rs.EnemiesScripts:FindFirstChild("Movement"):Clone()
local hpBar = rs.BillboardUi.HpBar:Clone()



for i, island in ipairs(workspace:WaitForChild("Islands"):GetDescendants()) do
    for i,v in ipairs(island:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("ObjectValue") then
            if v.Value == player  then
                print("1")
                local marine = rs.Enemies.OnePiece.Marine2:Clone()
                hpBar.Parent = marine
                move.Parent = marine
                anim.Parent = marine
                marine.Parent = island.Bodies:FindFirstChild("Enemies")
                marine.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = island:FindFirstChild("enemySpawner").CFrame * CFrame.new(0,10,0) * CFrame.Angles(0,3.2,0) 
                print("2")
            end
            print("is value")
        end
    
    end
end
```

Comment: print here to check if any part of code doesn't work(just for me)

Comment: You already used the trusty print debugging. What are the results? Is `1` even printed?

Comment: if i put wait(1) before "if v.Value == player  then..." everything works, but i want to optimise it